# How to embed the contents from a link on a mobile website

Tags: jsp, mobile-website, vs-web-application-project, html

I have to embed a add banner from a link source in my jsp page , and i followed the below steps

```
**<iframe src="xxx link" frameborder="0" target="_blank" target="_top" width="210" height="45" scrolling="no" ></iframe>**
```

or

```
 **<object  data="xxx link" vspace="0" >**
```

The xxx link given here which has nothing but a simple  image with a link to another page.
But by using the above 2 tags,when i m clicking on that image link my add page opens inside the same page, and also i need to re-size the frame size to fit that image properly in my mobile site and i don't want to use java script for this as it's not a good practice for a mobile site.

If there is any other way to do this or any changes in above code will fix the problem , then friends please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You seem to be confusing an [`iframe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/iframe) element with an [`a`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/a) element. What exactly do you want to happen? In response to what event(s)?

Comment: Thanks David for your response.                             Actually i have a DFP url to emebed in my jsp file, that dfp url generates a anchor tag with an image source dynamically for advertisement.By using some url parsing in my java code i can do this but i don't want it to be server side processing rather client side.So i just want to know the alternative ways to accomplish this or any solutions to the above problem.